# Groovy Script Error : java.io.NotSerializableException: com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvIterator

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

I have a small test stage in Jenkins groovy script to get the branch values by looping into a csv file , this works fine when I don't include the HELM_REPO_BRANCH in the loop but fails with java.io.NotSerializableException: com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvIterator error if i try to fetch the value from another function. Any idea how to resolve it ?.

```
stage("Deploy missing Services to ${DEST_ENV}"){
sh 'echo NAME,VERSION >test.csv'
sh 'echo account,1.17.1 >>test.csv'
sh 'echo payment,1.6.9 >>test.csv'
def csv  = readFile 'test.csv'
def data = new CsvParser().parse(csv)
 for( line in data ) {
    def SERVICE_NAME = "$line.NAME"
    def SRC_VERSION = "$line.VERSION"
    def HELM_REPO_BRANCH = get_job_parameters()
    echo "$SERVICE_NAME"
    echo "$SRC_VERSION"
    echo "$HELM_REPO_BRANCH"
  }
 } 

def get_job_parameters() {  
BRANCH= readFile 'deployment_branch.txt'    
return BRANCH
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [readCSV](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readcsv-read-content-from-a-csv-file-in-the-workspace) (assuming the stage is already running within the context of a `node` block):

```
stage("Deploy missing Services to ${DEST_ENV}") {
    writeFile file: 'test.csv', text: '''NAME,VERSION
account,1.17.1
payment,1.6.9'''
    def csv = readCSV(file: 'test.csv', format: CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader())
    csv.each { record ->
        def SERVICE_NAME = record.get('NAME')
        def SERVICE_VERSION = record.get('VERSION')
        ...
    }
}
```